# How do I make pycharm recognize a DLL as a valid import

Tags: python, import, dll, pycharm, warnings

First of all, my python script runs through without any issue. Please see below code and attached pic for pycharm's "Unresolved reference" warning sign, which I'm trying to get rid of.
Do I need to create a wrapper for the DLL for python to recognize it as a valid import module?

from Common.APIs import GeneratorAPI

[This pic shows the project folder structure containing the DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IPJA.png)

[This pic shows the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBBsh.png)

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and also [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: What if you rename *Common.dll* to *Common.pyd*?